# Removing an item from cart using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, cart

I am trying to create a shopping cart application. This is how my Firebase database looks like [Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsMTK.png)

So I have stored the cart details for each user using their User Id.

This is my code:

```
  DatabaseReference dataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cart_details/" + uid);
    dataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            long c = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            int count = (int) c;
            String show = "PRODUCT NAME    QUANTITY    PRICE";
            if (count > 0) {


                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

                    final LinearLayout la = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
                    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    la.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    final TextView tv = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                    final ImageButton btn1 = new ImageButton(getBaseContext());
                    final int j = i;

                    FirebaseAuth auth1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    String Uid = auth1.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    final DatabaseReference dataref1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cart_details/" + Uid + "/cart_" + i);
                    dataref1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        String pName;
                        String pQty_bag;
                        String pPrice_bag;


                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            Product pro = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                            pName = pro.name;
                            pQty_bag = pro.quantity;
                            pPrice_bag = pro.price;

                            //text
                            tv.setText("\n" + pName + "          " + pQty_bag + "            " + pPrice_bag);
                            tv.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK));
                            la.addView(tv);

                            //button
                            btn1.setId(j + 1);
                            btn1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.remove));
                            btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
                            final int index = j;
                            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dataref1.removeValue();
                                }
                            });
                            la.addView(btn1);


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    layout.addView(la);
                }



            } else {
                show = "There are no Items in the Cart";
                pay.setEnabled(false);
            }


            showCartContent.setText(show);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In the code, I iterate through the number of entries in particular user id and inside that I then retrieve all the values for each cart item.
Also for each cart item, I have added an image button (remove) that on clicked should remove the item.

So this is how the output appears

Now my problem is how do I remove the item, I tried using ref.removeValue(); but i keeps on crashing.

This is the crash log [crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z51LX.png)

Comment: well.. is that a nullPointerException? 
you have to make another function which will retrieve all the data from firebase and call it each time when you add item to cart and when you remove item from the cart

Comment: @Nikhya Yes!! It's a nullPointerException.Can you please me a little more specific!!

Comment: can you add the log for the crash

Comment: @OussemaAroua I have added the crash log in the question itself at the end.

Comment: the problem is that the `pro` field is null, try to log is